# NT problem (use mod) Solve this equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

This might not be solvable, but my NT teacher wanted us to give it a try.

> Solve $x_1^4 + x_2^4+\cdots+x_7^4 = 1,000,007$.

What has been figured out so far:

Mod $8$ to get the equation $= 7 \pmod 8$. Also with $\bmod 8$, all the numbers must be odd as $0-0$. $1-1$, $2-0$, $3-1$, etc.

If you make use of $\bmod 5$, also, $5$ of the integers are divisible by $5$.

Comment: If you can't solve it but have an idea that's great too! Remember this might not be solvable.

Comment: You probably won't be able to solve this without any brute force. I'm assuming you're solving this in integers. $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7\}=\{\pm1,\pm1,\pm3,\pm17,\pm21,\pm29,\pm11\}$ is a solution. You can use a program.


$$1\, 000\, 007=x_1^4+x_2^4+\cdots+x_7^4\ge x_i^4\implies x_i\le 31$$

for any $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,7\}$. You can stop here and use a program, or you can reduce the brute force further. As you've found, $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7$ are all odd (because $\left(a^4\bmod 8\right)\in \{0,1\}$ for any integer $a$).  
Exactly five of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7$ are divisible by $5$.

Comment: With a brute force program, we can see that the only solution (up to permutations and choice of signs) is the one user26486 has found. Also, your claim that "5 of the integers are divisible by 5" is false.

Comment: Right, either five of them are divisible by $5$ or neither of them is. It's a consequence of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).